# How to pack ARGB to one integer uniquely?

Tags: rgb

I have four integer values (0 - 255) for an ARGB color map.

Now I want to make a unique float or integer of these four integers. Is it possible to do it like the following?

```
sum  = 4 * 255 + A;
sum += 3 * 255 + R;
sum += 2 * 255 + G;
sum += 1 * 255 + B;
```

Is the value really unique?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are trying to do a base convert or something of that sort. Anyway the logic is like in base converting.
4 bytes = 32 bit. So 32 bit unsigned integer would do well.

In this case, you have:

```
ARGB = A<<24 + R<<16 + G<<8 + B
```

it's like this:
you have 4 bytes of data, meaning

```
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
```

where X is either 1 or 0 valued bit. You map them like this:

```
AAAAAAAA RRRRRRRR GGGGGGGG BBBBBBBB
```

and then all you have to do is to add them, but before that you shift the bits. You shift the `A` bits to the left, by 8*3 (to be beyond the limits of `R`, `G` and `B` bits), then shift the `R` bits by 8*2, and so on.

You end up adding these 32 bit integers:

```
AAAAAAAA 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 RRRRRRRR 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 GGGGGGGG 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 BBBBBBBB
```

Where `A`, `R`, `G`, `B` can be either `0` or `1`, and represent as a whole, the 8 bit value of the channel. Then you simply add them, and obtain the result. Or as [DarkDust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400056/darkdust) wrote, use not the `+` operator, but instead the `|` (bitwise or) operator, since it should be faster in this particular case.

Comment: ok for this example youre right really big thx :) i will now use it, but is my idea incorrect ? just for the next time it could be 5 ints and then theres no space left..

Comment: In your case, the resulting value can be achieved by different sets of A, R, G, B composites. Which means that the result does not identify the color correctly.

Comment: I found this answer super helpful, so thanks! @DarkDust's was as well, on the code side!

Answer (score 15):

You could do this:

Assuming `a`, `r`, `g` and `b` to be of type `unsigned char`/`uint8_t`:

```
uint32_t color = 0;
color |= a << 24;
color |= r << 16;
color |= g << 8;
color |= b;
```

Or more general (`a`, `r`, `g` and `b` being of any integer type):

```
uint32_t color = 0;
color |= (a & 255) << 24;
color |= (r & 255) << 16;
color |= (g & 255) << 8;
color |= (b & 255);
```

This will give you a unique integer for every ARGB combination. You can get the values back like this:

```
a = (color >> 24) & 255;
r = (color >> 16) & 255;
g = (color >> 8) & 255;
b = color & 255;
```

Comment: but is it possible to do it like my idea ? because its just working with less then 4 ints.. cause 32bit..

Comment: I really don't understand you, sorry, but the math of your solution is wrong. Your formula can be simplified to `sum = (10 * 255) + a + r + g + b`

Answer (score 6):

Not quite. You need to use bit-shifting and not simple multiplication.

Each value in your color map is 8 bytes long, correct? So in order for the resulting number to be unique, it must string them all together, for a total of 8*4=32 bits. Look at the following:

You want to take:

```
AAAAAAAA
RRRRRRRR
GGGGGGGG
BBBBBBBB
```

and make it look like:

```
AAAAAAAARRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBB
```

This means you have to add the following together:

```
AAAAAAAA000000000000000000000000
        RRRRRRRR0000000000000000
                GGGGGGGG00000000
                        BBBBBBBB
--------------------------------
AAAAAAAARRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBB
```

We accomplish this by bit-shifting to the left. Taking `A` and shifting 24 bits to the left will produce `AAAAAAAA` followed by 24 `0` bits, just like we want. Following that logic, you will want to do:

```
sum = A << 24 + R << 16 + G << 8 + B;
```

---

To illustrate why what you suggest (using multiplication) does not work, what you suggest results in the following binary numbers, which you can see overlap:

```
255 * 1 = 0011111111
255 * 2 = 0111111110
255 * 3 = 1011111101
255 * 4 = 1111111100
```

Furthermore, simply adding your A, R, G, B values to the resulting number will always be constant. Simplifying your math above we get:

```
4 * 255 + A + 3 * 255 + R + 2 * 255 + G + 1 * 255 + B
255 * (4 + 3 + 2 + 1) + A + R + G + B
255 * (10) + A + R + G + B
2550 + A + R + G + B
```

Oops.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<bitset>
void printBits(string s, int x)
{
    bitset <64> b(x);
    cout<<"\n"<<s<< " " << b;
}
long RGB(int a, int r, int g, int b)
{
    printBits("alpha    ", a);
    printBits("red      ", r);
    printBits("green    ", g);
    printBits("blue     ", b);

    long l = 0;

    l |= a << 24;
    l |= r << 16;
    l |= g << 8;
    l |= b;

    printBits("packed ARGB", l);

    return l;
}
```