# What does this syntax mean for turning argb into an integer?

Tags: java, rgb

This code works perfectly for what I am trying to do (set the color/alpha of a pixel on a bufferedimage) but I have no idea why it works. What does the syntax mean? I couldn't find documentation on it somehow.

```
int rgb = (alpha << 24) | red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
```

Also what form is the result? (What would it be called)
Lastly, is there a way to convert the img.getRGB() into sepperate a, r, g, b values?

Comment: The short answer: `<<` indicates a bit shift. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting can provide more information about it

Comment: Strongly related: [How to pack ARGB to one integer uniquely?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358533/how-to-pack-argb-to-one-integer-uniquely).

Answer (score 3):

This syntax combines bits of four eight-bit integer numbers ranging from 0 to 255 into a single 32-bit integer.

The `<<` operator shifts each 8-bit number into its final position in the 32-bit number, adding zeros to the "tail" as needed; the `|` operator then combines the four parts into a single number.

```
aaaaaaaa 00000000 00000000 00000000 // aaaaaaaa << 24
00000000 rrrrrrrr 00000000 00000000 // rrrrrrrr << 16
00000000 00000000 gggggggg 00000000 // gggggggg << 8
00000000 00000000 00000000 bbbbbbbb // bbbbbbbb
-----------------------------------
aaaaaaaa rrrrrrrr gggggggg bbbbbbbb
```

Each letter above corresponds to individual bits of each of the four components:

- `aaaaaaaa` are the eight bits of `alpha`
- `rrrrrrrr` are the eight bits of `red`
- `gggggggg` are the eight bits of `green`
- `bbbbbbbb` are the eight bits of `blue`

Answer (score 1):

The `<<` is the [left shift operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19): It moves the bits in the left-hand operand to the left by the number of places in the right-hand operand.

The `|` is a [bitwise OR operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1): It does an OR operation on each bit of the operands, returning a result where each bit is `1` if *either* operand had a `1` there, or `0` if **neither** did.

So it:

1. Takes the `alpha` value and shifts it 24 bits to the left
2. Takes the `red` value and shifts it 16 bits to the left
3. Takes the `green` value and shifts it 8 bits to the left
4. ORs the results together

So say you start out with

```
alpha = 106 (in binary: 00000000 00000000 00000000 01101010)
red =   255 (in binary: 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111)
green =  15 (in binary: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001111)
blue =  170 (in binary: 00000000 00000000 00000000 10101010)
```

So first it shifts the value of `alpha` 24 bits to the left:

```
alpha = 00000000 00000000 00000000 01101010
<< 24 becomes:
alpha = 01101010 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Then `red` 16 bits left:

```
red =   00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111
<< 16 becomes:
red =   00000000 11111111 00000000 00000000
```

Then `green` 8 bits left:

```
green = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001111
<< 9 becomes:
green = 00000000 00000000 00001111 00000000
```

Then it ORs them all together with `blue`:

```
alpha = 01101010 00000000 00000000 00000000
red =   00000000 11111111 00000000 00000000
green = 00000000 00000000 00001111 00000000
blue =  00000000 00000000 00000000 10101010
-------------------------------------------
rgb =   01101010 11111111 00001111 10101010
```

Answer (score 0):

It is using the left shift operator to construct a bitmask to construct the ARGB value which is defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space)